# Calculate distance with multiple starting coordinates

Tags: r, coordinates, euclidean-distance

I calculated the travelled distance called `distance_m` per date with the function `points_in_circle` for two ID's called `HEX_Tag_ID`. The coordinates that I put in the function are based on the `Datum` "2022-04-21" of the ID "3D6.15341BBB4F". However, the remaining ID has a different set of coordinates at the date "2022-04-21". That means that computations are wrongfully executed for "3D6.15341BC60F".

How can I automatise this function in order to calculate the travelled distance with the corresponding coordinates? especially if I want to add more ID's in the future. Key points: coordinates are based on `Datum` "2022-04-21" of every unique `HEX_Tag_ID.

```
library(spatialrisk)
Distance_ind <- points_in_circle(Distance_ind, lat_center = 51.93349, lon_center = 4.70912, lon = Longitude, lat = Latitude, radius = 1e6)
```

df = Distance_ind

```
structure(list(Datum_Tijd = structure(c(1650535073, 1653637570, 
1653285342, 1654242563, 1654578739, 1654837567, 1653899310, 1655108033, 
1653900853, 1653286920, 1653639081, 1654838913, 1653032146, 1655110494, 
1654580434, 1654244601, 1650533634), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Datum = structure(c(19103, 19139, 19135, 19146, 19150, 
19153, 19142, 19156, 19142, 19135, 19139, 19153, 19132, 19156, 
19150, 19146, 19103), class = "Date"), Tijd = c("11:57:53", "09:46:10", 
"07:55:42", "09:49:23", "07:12:19", "07:06:07", "10:28:30", "10:13:53", 
"10:54:13", "08:22:00", "10:11:21", "07:28:33", "09:35:46", "10:54:54", 
"07:40:34", "10:23:21", "11:33:54"), Reader_ID = c("A0", "A0", 
"A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", 
"A0", "A0", "A0", "A0"), HEX_Tag_ID = c("3D6.15341BBB4F", "3D6.15341BBB4F", 
"3D6.15341BBB4F", "3D6.15341BBB4F", "3D6.15341BBB4F", "3D6.15341BBB4F", 
"3D6.15341BBB4F", "3D6.15341BBB4F", "3D6.15341BC60F", "3D6.15341BC60F", 
"3D6.15341BC60F", "3D6.15341BC60F", "3D6.15341BC60F", "3D6.15341BC60F", 
"3D6.15341BC60F", "3D6.15341BC60F", "3D6.15341BC60F"), Longitude = c(4.70912, 
4.70917, 4.70918, 4.70918, 4.70914, 4.70914, 4.70927, 4.70921, 
4.70904, 4.70903, 4.70906, 4.709, 4.70901, 4.70903, 4.70902, 
4.70902, 4.70925), Latitude = c(51.933491, 51.934189, 51.9342, 
51.934269, 51.93428, 51.934292, 51.934341, 51.934441, 51.932499, 
51.932491, 51.932468, 51.932369, 51.93235, 51.932339, 51.932331, 
51.932308, 51.934891), x = c(108366.11, 108370.273, 108370.972, 
108371.043, 108368.304, 108368.317, 108377.308, 108373.285, 108359.578, 
108358.882, 108360.921, 108356.692, 108357.36, 108358.724, 108358.028, 
108358.004, 108376.503), y = c(438553.585, 438631.208, 438632.425, 
438640.102, 438641.351, 438642.686, 438648.054, 438659.218, 438443.273, 
438442.39, 438439.812, 438428.836, 438426.716, 438425.479, 438424.595, 
438422.037, 438709.256), `Lengte_(cm)` = c(9.7, 9.7, 9.7, 9.7, 
9.7, 9.7, 9.7, 9.7, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2, 
11.2, 11.2), Geslacht = c("vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", 
"vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", 
"vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw"), Sloot = c("22", 
"22", "22", "22", "22", "22", "22", "22", "22", "22", "22", "22", 
"22", "22", "22", "22", "22"), Lengte_8e_lichting = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12.5, NA, NA, NA
), Lengteklasse = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13"), class = "factor"), distance_m = c(0.111319490512219, 
77.8879654012696, 79.1440538153195, 86.8156131287763, 87.953110772786, 
89.2887843834125, 95.2906913528804, 106.044905287657, 110.454187269549, 
111.379609951795, 113.843032832766, 125.060674080157, 127.12861901825, 
128.277561285803, 129.201736097579, 131.75853920649, 156.213638336975
)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: why are you using nthe `points_in_circle`-function? Fro your question, it sounds like you want to calculate the (cumulative?) distance travelled (by ID) between rows. right?

Comment: It is important that the layout of my dataframe will be the same as my input dataframe in terms of columns and rows. This way I can see the travelled distances between different dates of every ID. But important is that the start date will always be 2022-04-21 and its corresponding coordinates, hope this make it a bit more clear :).

Comment: I use points_in_circle in the beginning because it was the only function I knew how to calculate distances between coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` + `geosphere` approach... It uses the `distGeo` to calculate distance from the first coordinate-pair (i.e. `c(Longitude[1], Latitude[1])`) of each `HEX_Tag_ID` with the current Longitude-Latitude of the row (`matrix(c(Longitude, Latitude), ncol = 2)`).

```
library(data.table)
library(geosphere)
# set to data.table format, sort by ID and Datumtijd
setDT(mydata, key = c("HEX_Tag_ID", "Datum_Tijd"))
# calculate distance
mydata[, distance := distGeo(
    c(Longitude[1], Latitude[1]), 
    matrix(c(Longitude, Latitude), ncol = 2)
  ),
  by = .(HEX_Tag_ID)]
```

Comment: absolutely beautiful! This seems to work perfectly, the only thing I don't understand is how it finds the row with coordinates from the date 2022-04-21 for each ID?

Comment: ah.. that it doen not.. ate least, not specifcally for that date. It sorts the data by HEX_ID and by Datetime (ascending), and the uses the first row of each HEX_ID as starting point for distance calculation. In your sampledata this happens to be on 2022-04-21 for both ID's.

Comment: note that the distance calulated is the distance between the starting point, and the current position., NOT the total distance traveled, and also not the distance travelend from the previous observation!!!

Comment: Yes, I understand now. And the way you calculated is exactly how I want it! So thanks a lot to you :)